# Is there a way of comparing/ evaluating a machine learning model with a recurrent model with a statistical significance test?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, statistical-significance, t-test, p-value

Comparing two different machine learning models (to assess if the difference between the mean performance is real or not using P-value and t-Statistic) is possible and strait forward in Python. Generally, is it possible to compare LSTM (requiring creating sequential data with time steps) with a machine learning model?

Comment: I wouldn't mix these things (deep neural networks and p-values), they are not really compatible.

Comment: @user2974951 Why? You have some model but want to try to improve upon it, so you collect data on its performance and the performance of a competitor. The competitor performs a bit better. Now you check if that performance improvement is statistically significant. That procedure makes sense to me.

Comment: @Dave And how do you propose we do that? How do we check statistical significance?

Comment: @user2974951 While Benavoli argues against doing so in favor of a Bayesian approach, the paper discusses approaches for calculating p-values. [Benavoli, Alessio, et al. "Time for a change: a tutorial for comparing multiple classifiers through Bayesian analysis." The Journal of Machine Learning Research 18.1 (2017): 2653-2688.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04316.pdf) // Because of the time component in this question, I do not believe Benavoli to quite apply, but certainly we can calculate p-values to compare some deep learning approaches.

Comment: Usually you also train the same network multiple times with different random initlizations.
 Technically one can do this for both approaches, and then do a two sample t-test. However, I would advise against it. Bc you can train the models as many times as you want and increase the "power" of your t-test. So basically any small difference can be found significant